# Как изменить цвет градиента при максимальной прокрутке recyclerview?

Tags: android, xaml

Мне нужно изменить цвет штуки, появляющейся при прокрутке recyclerview до предела:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял цвет всех таких штук в приложении задается `ColorPrimary` в теме, как я могу задать цвет для конкретного recyclerview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте цвет в атрибуте `android:colorEdgeEffect` в стиле приложения

```
<style name="AppTheme">
   <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#555555</item>
</style>
```

Если же его нужно убрать, то используйте атрибут `android:overScrollMode`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:overScrollMode="never"
```